# Перенос Excel в HTML

Tags: html, excel

Есть файл Excel, и надо перенести таблицу в HTML, сделал бы вручную, но там более 1 000 строк.

Подскажите, как перенести. Пробовал программу EXEL2HTML, не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Excel.
2. Качаем NVU, выделяем из екселя то, что нужно, и вставляем туды.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, насколько будет удобно: я беру сохраняю в .csv а потом использую [это](https://github.com/ShilGen/my_lib/blob/master/tablefromcsv.php).